# Command line MSBuild not exluding Debug libraries

Tags: msbuild, uwp, azure-devops, windows-store

So I have build a UWP application which I have built an `.appxupload` package through Visual Studio and submitted it to the store and it has been accepted to the store fine.

I am now trying to use Visual Studio Online to Automate my build process.

I am building my project in a new configuration I have defined called **AppStore** that looks like the following:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'AppStore|AnyCPU'">
    <OutputPath>bin\AppStore\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

And my Command line arguments for the Automated build are:

```
/p:Configuration=AppStore;AppxBundle=Always;AppxBundlePlatforms="x86|x64|ARM";AppxPackageDir="$(Build.BinariesDirectory)\AppxPackages\\";UapAppxPackageBuildMode=StoreUpload
```

This then created my `.appxupload` package on request which was great.. BUT... when I uploaded to the store I get the following:

> Debug configuration
>
> Error Found: The debug configuration test detected the following errors:
>
> The binary MyApp.Logging.dll is built in debug mode.
>
> The binary MyApp.Reports.dll is built in debug mode.
>
> The binary MyApp.DataAccess.dll is built in debug mode.
>
> The binary MyApp.Business.dll is built in debug mode.
>
> The binary MyApp.Core.dll is built in debug mode.

Are my MsBuild arguments incorrect?

**Update**

this is the command MSBuild is running:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild.exe" "C:\agent\_work\1\s\MyApp\MyApp\MyApp.UWP\MyApp.UWP.csproj" /nologo /nr:false /t:"Clean" /dl:CentralLogger,"C:\agent\_work\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.118.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll";"RootDetailId=ebe5f0fb-1da0-4f6b-aa54-d80c73ac3060|SolutionDir=C:\agent\_work\1\s\MyApp\MyApp\MyApp.UWP"*ForwardingLogger,"C:\agent\_work\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.118.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll" /p:Configuration=AppStore;AppxBundle=Always;AppxBundlePlatforms="x86|x64|ARM";AppxPackageDir="C:\agent\_work\1\b\AppxPackages\\";UapAppxPackageBuildMode=StoreUpload /p:configuration="AppStore" /p:VisualStudioVersion="15.0" /p:_MSDeployUserAgent="VSTS_7c0e42bd-65b9-486e-9338-1c87ca14bb55_build_3_1182"
```

It seems to produce `x86` in Release mode and `x64` and `ARM` in debug and thats where my app fails Windows Certification Checks

Comment: You have defined the `TRACE` symbol. Is this intentional?

Comment: Not intentionally. Just left the default configurations. Could this be forcing it to build as Debug?

Comment: Since one of the libraries in the diagnostic message indicates, that *"MyApp.Logging.dll"* is built in debug mode, and the `TRACE` symbol controls logging, I wouldn't be surprised if that were part of the issue. I'd remove it. After all, tracing function calls is not something a release configuration should be doing.

Comment: If I create a brand new UWP project that option is ticked for `Release` mode. It might be the default

Comment: Does adding `<DebugSymbols>false</DebugSymbols>` to the property group change this behaviour?

Comment: @MartinUllrich: Generation of debug symbols does not change code generation. Debug symbols are compiled into separate .pdb files. Besides, you *do* want to generate debug symbols for release configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to these steps to change configuration:

1. Right click solution file in VS > Configuration Manager
2. Select AppStore configuration
3. Change configurations of MyApp.Logging, MyApp.Reports, MyApp.DataAccess … (e.g. release)

Comment: Think this is actually if you build using `MsBuild command line` any build apart from `Release` creates debug `.appxupload` files. Creating an `.appxupload` from VS and `MSBuild` for the same configuration (mycustomconfiguration) have different outcomes. VS passes app certification, MSBuild doesnt

Comment: @user1 Which build task you used? Try to add /t:[UWP project name] argument and build the solution directly. (/t:[UWP project name] /p:Configuration=AppStore;AppxBundle=Always;AppxBundlePlatforms="x86|x64|ARM";AppxPackageDir="$(Build.BinariesDirectory)\AppxPackages\\";UapAppxPackageBuildMode=StoreUpload

Comment: I will try the above. I am using the MSBuild task. I have added the command that is being run to my question

Comment: I tried the above but got the error `The target "C:\agent\_work\1\s\MyApp\MyApp\MyApp.UWP\MyApp.UWP.csproj" does not exist in the project.`

Comment: @user1 You can use Visual Studio Build task instead. Your project name is MyApp.UWP, so use /t:MyApp_UWP instead. If the project in an additional folder, then use /t:[folder]/MyApp_UWP.